# Object.send("#{field}<<",value)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This works.

```
profile.educations << education_model
```

But this doesn't

```
profile.send("#{model_name.underscore.pluralize}<<", model_model)
```

where

```
model_name = "Education"
model_model = model_name.constantize.new
```

and gives me the following error

```
undefined method `Educations<<' for #<Profile:0x007f20dc1089a8>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach doesn't work because `educations` and `<<` are separate methods which cannot be chained like you try. Since you don't need to get `<<` method name dynamically, you can call it in regular way, without using `send`. Also, you should call `underscore` on your `model_name`, because rails convention is that association names (and more generally - method names) are underscored. So the following should work:

```
profile.send("#{model_name.underscore.pluralize}") << model_model
```

Comment: Thank you. I just got it to work myself also. I was also forgetting to downcase. So it should have been. profile.send("#{model_name.downcase.pluralize}") << model_model

Comment: @patrick_corrigan I'd advice using `underscore`, since `downcase` won't work for complex model names, like `UserProfile`.

Comment: Why can I chain = like that. eg profile.send("#{model_name.pluralize}=", [model_model])

Comment: @patrick_corrigan because `=` is a part of a method name, setter methods are named in this way in Ruby.